# How to make buttons call functions

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x

After defining my word count method thanks to another member, I am now creating a GUI to go along with it. I have created three buttons, one for browsing for a file, one for counting the words and lines in a file, and one for exiting.

My question is, how do I make these buttons do things? I am trying to make the "Browse for a file" run the `filename = fileopenbox()` line, and the "Count" button run the `word_count()` method.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
from tkinter import *
from easygui import fileopenbox

root = Tk()
root.title("Word Counter")
root.geometry("500x500")

app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
button1 = Button(app, text = "Browse for a file")
button1.grid()

button2 = Button(app)
button2.grid()
button2.configure(text ="Count the file")

button3 = Button(app)
button3.grid()
button3["text"] = "Exit"

root.mainloop()

def word_count(filename):
    filename = fileopenbox()
    if not filename.endswith(('.txt', '.py', '.java')):
        print('Are you trying to annoy me? How about giving me a TEXT or SOURCE CODE file, genius?')
        return

    with open(filename) as f:
        n_lines = 0
        n_words = 0
        for line in f:
            n_lines += 1
            n_words += len(line.split())
    print('Your file has {} lines, and {} words'.format(n_lines, n_words))
```

Comment: Pass callback as command keyword argument: `Button(...., command=callback)`

Comment: I'm kind of confused, can you give me an example without the "...?"

Here's what I interpreted it as "Button(fileopenbox(), command=callback)" but that just makes the fileopenbox() method run immediately when running the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the reference to the function you want to execute as the `command` option. Since you are divinding the task in two steps (one button to ask for the file name, and another one to count the lines and the words), I'd suggest you to create a class to wrap everything.

Besides, I suggest you to remove the dependency of `easygui` - since it is a project that is not longer maintained - and replace it with `filedialog.askopenfilename`, which is part of the standard library:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showwarning, showinfo


class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.filename = None
        button1 = Button(self, text="Browse for a file", command=self.askfilename)
        button2 = Button(self, text ="Count the file", command=self.word_count)
        button3 = Button(self, text="Exit", command=master.destroy)
        button1.grid()
        button2.grid()
        button3.grid()
        self.grid()
    def askfilename(self):
        filename = askopenfilename()
        if not filename.endswith(('.txt', '.py', '.java')):
            showwarning('Are you trying to annoy me?', 'How about giving me a TEXT or SOURCE CODE file, genius?')
        else:
            self.filename = filename
    def word_count(self):
        if self.filename:
            with open(self.filename) as f:
                n_lines = 0
                n_words = 0
                for line in f:
                    n_lines += 1
                    n_words += len(line.split())
            showinfo('Result', 'Your file has {} lines, and {} words'.format(n_lines, n_words))
        else:
            showwarning('No file selected', 'Select a file first')


root = Tk()
root.title("Word Counter")
root.geometry("500x500")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the console's output appear on the Tkinter frame?

Comment: @DavonG Yes, the easiest way is with a dialog. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hmm, the info seems to appear in the title bar instead of the grid. hehe http://i.imgur.com/JCWidln.png

Comment: @DavonG True, I didn't test the code. The first argument of `showinfo` is the title, and the second one is the text, so it should be `showinfo('Result', 'Your file has...')`. I have changed it in the answer too.

Comment: Added a couple of things, every thing going great so far after your solution. But last 2 questions (I promise!!!)
1. Is there a way to change the icon of Tkinter at the top left of the frame
2. When I click "Count the file" before browsing for a file. I want an error to pop up saying "choose a file first." How do I do this?

Comment: @DavonG No worries ;) 1: Yes, `root.wm_iconbitmap('path/to/icon')`. 2: It is already in my answer, see the `else` clause in the `word_count` method.

Comment: When I click count, I see this is the console http://i.imgur.com/q48cqX6.png but nothing actually pops up in the program. (Also the program still works fine after that console error...only problem is no popup)

Comment: @DavonG Yes, that's because `self.filename` is not defined yet, so it should be defined in the constructor. I've edited my answer.